# Exclude products with product shortocde Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to exclude products with shortcode but its not working

here is what i am using shortocode

```
[products limit="14" orderby="id" columns="4" order="DESC" visibility="visible" category="tcs" cat_operator="NOT IN"]
```

[image]

I used php filter also

```
function phl_customize_product_shortcode( $args, $atts ) {
    
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'name',
                'terms'    => array( 'tcs' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
       );

    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'phl_customize_product_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

But still not working

here is site you can see

```
https://www.pottershouselimited.co.uk
```

Comment: Intresting. I'm also trying to answer another question on Stackoverflow with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this:

```
function phl_customize_product_shortcode( $args, $atts ) {
    
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'tcs' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
       );

    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'phl_customize_product_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

and tell me how it goes? also where on the website can i see the tcs items on homepage?

Comment: Yes its working

Comment: What if i want multiple categories hide, Uncategorized, etc,etc

Comment: great. for multiple categories, instead of `array( 'tcs' )` use `array( 'tcs', 'x', 'y', 'z' )`. the important thing is that category name and category slug are different. in category section in woocommerce panel you have a list of categories with their slugs. use those words here instead of x, y and z and so on.